execute parent query first and pass the the criteria to subquery
I need to execute parent sql query first and pass the the criteria to subquery:
select 
    emp_id, dept_location from Department dept, (select * from  employee) emp 
where emp.dept_no=dept_no and dept.name ="Finance" 

In the above example, i do not want  all the records in the employee table  to be fetched  first and then join condition to be applied. I am looking for a query hint , that fetches records for only finance department in the subquery.

Why do you have a subquery at all? Why not just join directly to employee? If you join normally, Oracle will (usually) figure out the most efficient way to do it (and sometimes will even if you don't). If you think you need a hint to get an efficient plan you might be mistaken, or doing something wrong, at least for a simple query with up-to-date statistics.

I just gave example. This kind of query is  being generated by an etl framework.

Just join the two queries and don't use a sub-query:
SELECT emp.emp_id,
       dept.dept_location
FROM   Department dept
       INNER JOIN employee emp 
       ON emp.dept_no = dept.dept_no
WHERE  dept.name = 'Finance'

If you want to you could use a LATERAL join (but an INNER JOIN is simpler and may be more efficient):
SELECT emp.emp_id,
       dept.dept_location
FROM   Department dept
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   employee emp 
         WHERE  emp.dept_no = dept.dept_no
       ) emp
WHERE  dept.name = 'Finance'

Note: Double quotes (i.e. "Finance") are for an identifier for a column with a mixed-case name. A string literal uses single quotes 'Finance'.
